# Looping through facebook api "likes"

Tags: php, arrays, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

Hey all i am trying to get all the likes for a wall post in PHP. The array frame looks like this:

```
Array ( 
[data] => Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [id] => XXXXXXXX_XXXXXXXXXXX 
        [from] => Array ( 
            [name] => Bob Barker
            [id] => XXXXXXXXXXX
        ) 
        [message] => This is a message here!!! 
        [story] => We shared a message with others
        [story_tags] => Array ( 
            [0] => Array ( 
                [0] => Array ( 
                    [id] => XXXXXXXXXX 
                    [name] => Bob Barker
                    [offset] => 0 
                    [length] => 11 
                    [type] => user 
                ) 
            ) 
            [19] => Array ( 
                [0] => Array ( 
                    [id] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 
                    [name] => NAME 
                    [offset] => 19 
                    [length] => 5 
                    [type] => page 
                ) 
            ) 
        ) 
        [picture] => [removed] 
        [link] => [removed]
        [name] => Timeline Photos 
        [caption] => This is just a caption for the post here 
        [properties] => Array ( 
            [0] => Array ( 
                [name] => By 
                [text] => NAME 
                [href] => [removed] 
            ) 
        ) 
        [icon] => https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yD/r/aS8ecmYRys0.gif 
        [actions] => Array ( 
            [0] => Array ( 
                [name] => Like 
                [link] => [removed]
            ) 
        ) 
        [privacy] => Array ( 
            [value] => 
        ) 
        [type] => photo 
        [status_type] => shared_story 
        [object_id] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        [application] => Array ( 
            [name] => Photos 
            [id] => XXXXXXXXXX 
        ) 
        [created_time] => 2014-02-12T21:33:17+0000 
        [updated_time] => 2014-02-12T21:33:17+0000 
        [likes] => Array ( 
            [data] => Array ( 
                [0] => Array ( 
                    [id] => XXXXXXXXXXXX 
                    [name] => John Doe 
                ) 
                [1] => Array ( 
                    [id] => XXXXXXXXXXXX 
                    [name] => Steve Doe 
                ) 
            ) 
            [paging] => Array ( 
                [cursors] => Array ( 
                    [after] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 
                    [before] => XXXXXXXXXXXX== 
                ) 
            ) 
        ) 
    )
```

My current PHP code is:

```
$feed = $facebook->api('/me/home'); //This is the array above

foreach($feed['data'] as $post) {
  $story = (isset($post['story']) ? $post['story'] : null);
  $id = (isset($post['id']) ? $post['id'] : null);
  $name = (isset($post['name']) ? $post['name'] : null);
  $message = (isset($post['message']) ? $post['message'] : null);
  $post_link = (isset($post['actions'][0]['link']) ? $post['actions'][0]['link'] : null);
  $picture = (isset($post['picture']) ? $post['picture'] : null);

  foreach($post['likes'] as $liked) {
      echo $post['id'];
  }

  echo $name . ' ' . $story . ' it was: ' . $message . ' and ' . $post_link .  ' and <img src="' . $picture . '" /><br />';
  echo '=======================================================================================================';
}
```

The

```
foreach($post['likes'] as $liked) {
      echo $post['id'];
}
```

doesnt seem to be working as-is. What am i missing in order to make it loop through all the "liked" posts in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes

```
foreach($post['likes'] as $liked) {
      echo $post['id'];
}
```

will not work since

`$post['likes']` elements are again a nested array as

```
likes => array => data => array=> ..
```

So you need to do the loop as

```
if(array_key_exists('data',$post['likes'])){
        foreach($post['likes']['data'] as $liked=>$val) {
            echo '<br />Like ID: ' .$val["id"].'<br />' ;
        }
    }
```

It is always better to do a check if the array key exists before doing the loop, so that if the returned data does not contain the key you do not get undefined index error.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
foreach($post['likes']->data as $like) {
  echo $like->id;
}
```